# How to execute Shell Script ,while booting up EC2 Machine?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ec2-ami

I want to execute shell script whenever I start my ec2 (Linux )instance first time 
Any Suggestion Please.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being you can add the entries/command in initrd file and you can create a softlink for it. This will help you to execute the shell script whenever u will start your linux machine whether it is on EC2 or on linux.

Comment: Nice explanation and usage of initrd to start services at Linux machine boot up.

Answer (score 0):

See "[Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)".

You can use "user data" or "cloud-init" to do it. There's a section when manually launching EC2 instances to add the user data, and you can do it through APIs too.

[image: user data goes here]